# Return MySQL result after query execution using node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, return, return-value

I want to return the MySQL result into a variable.
I tried the following but it's not working, as I am getting an empty variable.

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const db    = require('../config/db');
const connection = mysql.createConnection(db);    

module.exports = class Categories {
   constructor (res) {
       this.res = res;
   }

   getCategories() {
       connection.query("SELECT * FROM `categories`", (error, results, fields) => {
           if (error) throw error;
           this.pushResult(results);
       });
   }

   pushResult(value) {
       this.res = value;
       return this.res;
   }
};
```

Comment: move `this.pushResult();` inside the callback

Comment: @RolandStarke, sorry I have updated my code.

Comment: @RolandStarke still having the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just made a callback function first:

```
var Categories = {

    getCategories: function (callback) {
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM `categories`", (error, results, fields) => {
            if(error) { console.log(err); callback(true); return; }
            callback(false, results);
        });
    }

};
```

And then used it with route:

```
app.get('/api/get_categories', (req, res) => {

    categories.getCategories(function (error, results) {
        if(error) { res.send(500, "Server Error"); return; }
        // Respond with results as JSON
        res.send(results);
    });

});
```